# Add Editor templates row by row to Html Table and send to controller

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, html-table, mvc-editor-templates

i have two model classes **Money** and **MoneyType**.

a money object containe a **List of TypeMoney** property

In my money strongly typed view, that's the main index view there's html table for the list of type Money objects

i want to append TypeMoney object as editor template row to table dynamicly by jquery, so that when the user want to fill one row , he click on **AddMoney button**, then only one row is displayed in this table. (the user will fill typemoney informations). and he click again on **AddMoney  button**, when he want to fill information in an other row and so on.

for this i have implemented an editor template and i created a partial view _create.cshtml for this editor template so that i can append this partial as row

untill he submit all to controller: the **money object** data with its **collection of typeMoney objects** data.

In the controller index action i passed a model "**money**"  to Index view

My issue is when i submit this form, **the list of type money objects** is sent null to the controller

How i can add **a type money object** to Editor template collection and send this collection without to be null to controller

sorry for the lot of a details, because i want that all to be clear and understandable . if there's a thing not cleer. please tell me.

model classes

```
public class Money{
    public int StructureId {get; set;}
    // public enum Quarter:byte{ FirstQuarter = 1, SecondQuarter=2, 
    //  ThirdQuarter=3, FourthQuarter=4}
    public Querter Quarter{get; set;}
    public int Year {get; set;}
    public List<TypeMoney> MoneyTypes {get; set;}
}

public class TypeMoney{
    //public enum Type:byte{ Bill= 1, Coin=2}
    public Type Type{get; set;}
    //public enum Value = {one = 1, tow=2, five=5, ten=10, Etc};
    public Value Value{get; set;}
    public int Number{get; set;}

}
```

controller code

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    ViewBag.StructureId= new SelectList(GetStructures(), "Id", "Name");
    ViewBag.Year = new SelectList(GetYears());
    ViewBag.Quater =  new SelectList(Enum.GetValue(typeof(Quarter));

    return View()
 }

 //partial view for Editor template
 public PartialViewResult _Create(Money money)
 {
     return PartialView(); 
 }
 //save money with list of typeMoney objects 
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(Money money)
 {
     //code for save in database
 }
```

Here is my editor template

```
@model ProjectName.TypeMoney

<tr class="insertMoneyTr">
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, null, "--selectionnez--", 
 new { @class = "typeMoney form-control" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Valeur, null, new { @class = 
        "valueMoney form-control" })

    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Numbre, new { @class = "nombre form- 
        control" })
    </td>

    <td>
        <button class="deleteMoney btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon- 
        remove">
       </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Partial View _create.cshtml

```
@model ProjectName.TypeMoney

 @Html.EditorForModel();
```

The jquery code for display  a partial view as row appened to table

```
//the id of button that append editor template is AddMoney

$("#AddMoney").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "Money/_Create",
                    type: 'Get',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#listEspecesDiv tbody").append(result);
                    }
                });


            });
```